# Standardized parameters for elliptic curve cryptography

Tags: elliptic-curves

When an elliptic curve-based cryptosystem is deployed, a single set of public parameters (consisting of a particular elliptic curve over a finite field as well as a generator of a prime order subgroup of its group of points) is typically shared across all users.

Some of these public parameters are standardized in some form. The best known ones are NIST-approved curve parameters, described as part of the FIPS 186-{2,3} standard, but there are others. For example, a French agency [recently released](http://www.ssi.gouv.fr/fr/anssi/publications/publications-scientifiques/autres-publications/publication-d-un-parametrage-de-courbe-elliptique-visant-des-applications-de.html) a set of parameters recommended for local security applications (possibly over concerns re the security of curves over the very special base fields used by NIST?—they didn't say).

Is a list of such curve parameters compiled somewhere? Do you know any aside from the previous ones?

Comment: The French authorities gave the following rationale for their [FRP256v1](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do;jsessionid=?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000024668816) curve: "The proposed parameters correspond to a _randomly generated_ curve, selected as to obey usual security criteria" (_my emphasis_); I infer that (at least one of) the motivation was to avoid a special field as in P-256 of [FIPS 186-3](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf). The "usual security criteria" are likely those in [RGS annex B1](http://www.ssi.gouv.fr/IMG/pdf/RGS_B_1.pdf), section 2.2.1.4.

Comment: One can infer that indeed, but on the other hand, the Digital Signature Standard says that NIST-approved curves are randomly generated (and even “provably” so!) in the sense that the curve coefficients are chosen using a hash function (even though the base fields are quite special). So it seems difficult to tell what exactly *randomly generated* means in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few more standards, with (sometimes) overlapping sets of parameters:

- [ANSI X9.62](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ANSI%20X9.62:2005)
- [SECG](http://www.secg.org/?action=secg,docs_secg)
- [Brainpool](http://www.ecc-brainpool.org/)

Comment: Actually there is considerable overlap: all 15 FIPS 186-2/3 curves are part of the 20 curves that X9.62 lists in its annex L; and all these 20 curves are part of the curves listed in SEC 2. The Brainpool curves are (deliberately) separate.

Comment: Also, the AACS standard (protection on HD-DVD and Blu-ray discs) uses ECDSA in their own curve (see [this document](http://www.aacsla.com/specifications/AACS_Spec_Common_Final_0952.pdf)), page 10). When Sony designed the protection system for the PS3, they defined no less than 64 new curves (and they totally botched their ECDSA implementation, but that's another story).